# Firebase sms description language to change

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The language does not change to Russian.
What could be the problem

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
auth.setLanguageCode("ru")

val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
        .setPhoneNumber(..)
        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setActivity(requireActivity())
        .setCallbacks(..)
        .build()

PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from firebase
Firebase>your project > authentication >templates > SMS verification
and you will see buttom of the page "templates language"
and click and select language are you want

Comment: I wanted to do it through code `setLanguageCode(Locale.getDefault().language)`